# Copy file into a specific parent folder with Google Drive API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm using Python 2.7 and a [service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390913/how-to-authenticate-as-myself-for-google-drive-api) to copy a file in Google Drive into another folder based on its title. This requires me to execute five (5!) commands:

1. Find file ID by title. ([`files().list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list))
2. Find parent folder ID by title ([`files().list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list))
3. Copy file ([`files().copy`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy))
4. Transfer ownership to a real account ([`files().insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert))
5. Move into the parent folder. ([`parents().insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert))

This all works but I'd like to reduce the number of calls and first that means caching the ID's so I don't have to call `files().list`. The next thing I'm trying to do, and specifically where I'm at with this question, is how to set the parent folder *within* the `files().copy` command. The documentation has an optional `parents` parameter described like so:

> Collection of parent folders which contain this file. Setting this field will put the file in all of the provided folders. On insert, if no folders are provided, the file will be placed in the default root folder.

Although it doesn't say, I know it means parent *ID's* since that's what is used everywhere else. However, setting this array in the client library doesn't produce an effect: no error and the file is definitely not in the right folder.

```
newfile = {'title': newtitle, 'parents' : [ parentFolderId ]}
service.files().copy(fileId=originalId, body=newfile).execute()
```

Has anyone had any luck [with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358723/save-file-in-specific-folder-with-google-drive-sdk-java)? Is there something else I'm missing?

Bonus: transfer ownership in copy command? Perhaps my service account could impersonate me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah ha! The `parents` array is a list of objects with the `id` field:

```
newfile = {'name': newtitle, 'parents' : [ { "id" : parentFolderId } ]}
service.files().copy(fileId=originalId, body=newfile).execute()
```

I'll update this if/when I figure out how to set permissions also.

One strange note here is that the file is *still* being copied to the drive root as well as the parent folder(s) I specify.

Comment: +1 Good catch! This just saved me from some trouble :)

Comment: if there are child folder then what can i do ?

Comment: in the Google Drive V3 API "parents" IS an array of folder IDs as plain strings. Also the "title" parameter becomes "name". That will teach me to copy and paste SO posted code.

Comment: {'name': new_title, 'parents' : [ target_folder_id ]}