# Drive API v3 - Copy with Parents

Tags: python, google-drive-api

When I'm trying to copy a Docs file from a template I have, I set the parents in the request body like so:

```
dummy_id = '17OGNsO6prLwjtaeVbfgQv41ogtrAawDqvPUOSm4B9bk'
target_folder_id = '0ALbScsczry1nUi9PVA'

file_metadata = {
    'name': 'Test Project Quote',
    'parents': [{'id': target_folder_id}]  # This is where you set the target folder
}
test_file = self.drive_service.files().copy(fileId=dummy_id,
                                            body=file_metadata,
                                            supportsAllDrives=True,  # TODO this is deprecated
                                            fields='id,parents').execute()
```

However, it doesn't seem to create the copy in this folder but just performs the default operation of creating the copy in the same drive as the original - it inherits the parents. The odd thing is that this did seem to work once, but not every time. Is there something obviously wrong with the above? (I jumbled up the IDs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace**

`'parents': [{'id': target_folder_id}]`

**by**

`'parents': [target_folder_id]`

The variable `parents` expects simply an array of 1 or more parent ids (comma separated), not a key - value object.

Comment: Uhh, that's so obvious ahah. That's clearly what is stated in the docs but I wasn't sure how to interpret them given this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415467/copy-file-into-a-specific-parent-folder-with-google-drive-api
Thanks!